# Why would the Pilot on a natural gas fluctuates then goes out

Tags: heating

Why would the pilot on a natural gas heater fluctuates and go out?

It sometimes does not fluctuate and works for hours, then all of a sudden flame on pilot dwindles to a fine blue flame with no flame between the tip and the pilot before it shuts down.

This is the 4th heater I've tried with the same results.

Comment: Pressure at the meter was around 7.6

Comment: `dwindles to a fine blue flame` .... what color is it when it works normally?

Comment: I was wondering if the gas company has issues with their lines

Comment: @NeilLarkins Your best bet is to call the gas company and find out. We can't make that determination from here. If the problem happens with multiple heaters, it's either an issue with the gas company's pipes or your pipes.

Comment: Is there a drip leg?  Sometimes a little moisture in the line can cause this problem. A drip leg is a T after the shutoff valve with a length of pipe that is capped pointing down any where from 4" to 12"  moisture and rust fall into the leg and prevent this from causing an issue. I had 1 home that had a long drip leg and I had to clean it several times a year, after cleaning and using gas approved pipe dope to seal it up test with gas leak solution or soapy water and make sure there are no bubbles, if no drip leg adding one is not hard and could solve the problem